# c# Делегаты - плюсы и минусы

Tags: c#, ооп, делегаты

Начал изучать делегаты и их использование без событий. Просмотрел много разных статей, книг и примеров. И в принципе суть делегатов я понял. Но не понял пары вещей: А в чем собственно преимущество, так сказать достоинства, использования делегатов?  И есть ли минусы у делегатов, как таковых?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33749/discussion-on-question-by-lcnw-c----).

Answer (score 7):

События - это всего лишь частный случай применения делегатов. Сам делегат - по сути ссылка на произвольный метод со строго заданной сигнатурой. Говорить о преимуществах и недостатках можно лишь в сравнении с реализациями в других языках. Тонкости использования, разумеется, есть и подробно описаны у того же Рихтера. Для более развернутого ответа нужен более конкретный вопрос.

Answer (score 4):

Делегаты позволяют вызывать методы не знаю их имя.
Например, есть два класса

```
class B
{
    public void M(int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B.M:" + i);
    }
}

class A
{
    public void M1(int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A.M1:" + i);
    }

    static public void M2(int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A.M2:" + i);
    }
}
```

Требуется определить метод, который будет вызывать методы B.M, A.M1, A.M2 или любой другой метод, с аналогичной сигнатурой.

Для этого определим делегат

```
delegate void TestMethod(int i);
```

В определении делегата возвращаемый тип и типы параметров аналогичны тем, что определены у методов B.M, A.M1, A.M2

Определим метод для вызова делегата:

```
void Test(TestMethod m) { 
  m(1); 
}
```

в него можно передавать 'ссылки' на разные методы, включая static, из разных классов.

```
var a = new A();
Test(a.M1);
Test(A.M2);

var b = new B();
Test(b.M);
```

результат

```
A.M1:1
A.M2:1
B.M:1
```

---

На основе делегатов определяются события.
Например, событие можно определить так:

```
event TestMethod Tests;
```

при этом также создается наследник класса [MulticastDelegate](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/multicastdelegate.cs,115d292376227fdb).

```
Console.WriteLine(Tests.GetType().BaseType.Name);  // MulticastDelegate

var a = new A();
var b = new B();

// добавим обработчики в событие Tests
Tests += a.M1;
Tests += A.M2;
Tests += b.M;

/* другой способ добавления обработчиков в событие
Tests = (TestMethod)Delegate.Combine(Tests, new TestMethod(a.M1));
Tests = (TestMethod)Delegate.Combine(Tests, new TestMethod(A.M2));
Tests = (TestMethod)Delegate.Combine(Tests, new TestMethod(b.M)); 
*/

// посылаем событие, при этом вызываются обработчики
Tests(1);
```

результат

```
A.M1:1
A.M2:1
B.M:1
```

---

Для чего надо указывать event?

```
class C {
  public TestMethod Tests1;
  public event TestMethod Tests2;
}

var c = new C();
var i1 = c.Tests1.GetInvocationList(); 
var i2 = c.Tests2.   // error CS0070, т.к. нет доступа к свойствам и методам
```

Tests2 можно вызвать только из методов/свойств класса С. Для этого в класс надо добавить, например, метод:

```
public void Run() {
  var e = this.Tests2;
  if(e != null) 
    e(1);
}
```

Comment: те кто минусы ставит, напишите что не так?

Comment: вы ответили не на тот вопрос, который был задан

Comment: @PavelMayorov _"вы ответили не на тот вопрос, который был задан"_ -- в впросе сказано "в чем собственно преимущество". У меня в ответе и показано основное назначение=преимущество. Вы знаете другое? Напишите какое.

Comment: назначение не есть преимущество. Преимущество может быть только по отношению к альтернативным вариантам.

Comment: @PavelMayorov _"Преимущество может быть только по отношению к альтернативным вариантам"_ -- а есть альтернатива? обратите внимание что вопрос начинается с фразы "Начал изучать делегаты и их использование без событий".

Comment: вот именно, автору вопроса надо *сравнение* делегатов и событий, как бы глупо это не звучало, а не простой рассказ о них

Comment: @PavelMayorov _"автору вопроса надо сравнение делегатов и событий"_ -- автору нужны делегаты "без событий". и это хорошо. дело в том, что многие не понимают, что делегаты сами по себе. их можно использовать без событий. и неправильно сравнивать события (т.е. надстройку - фактически синтаксический сахар) с фундаметом - делегатами.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, преимущества не обязательно должны с чём-то сравниваться. Если женщина красивая, то её красота это её преимущество. Её никто не сравнивает с уродиной.

Comment: @ixSci, но тогда должны быть указаны критерии, по которым именно эта женщина красивая

Comment: @Grundy, зачем критерии? Человек спрашивает «вот у меня есть барышня, вот вам её биография и т.п.: расскажите какие плюсы и минусы есть у моей барышни?»

Comment: @ixSci, ага :-) только для одних могут быть плюсы, а для других то же самое будет минусом :-D

Comment: @Grundy, безусловно. Поэтому плюсы и минусы будут, во многом, субъективны. Но делегаты чуть проще, чем женщины, поэтому тут можно представить достаточно плюсов и минусов, к этому моменту найденных сообществом программистов. Т.е. такие + и -, которые разделяет значительное кол-во людей.

Comment: @ixSci, ага, можете указать эти общепринятые плюсы/минусы в данном ответе?:)

Answer (score 3):

События - это механизм работающий на основе делегатов. Синтаксис для реализации событий по умолчанию

```
public class MyClass
{
    public event EventHandler SomeEvent;
}
```

разворачивается в что-то вроде

```
public class MyClass
{
    // виден изнутри класса как SomeEvent, вызываем
    private EventHandler SomeEventHandlers;

    // виден снаружи класса как SomeEvent, предоставляет синтаксис += и -=
    public event EventHandler SomeEvent
    {
        add
        {
            SomeEventHandlers += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            SomeEventHandlers -= value;
        }
    }
}
```

т.е. сам по себе вопрос о "преимуществах" и "минусах" некорректен. Если вам нужна семантика события

- сам факт наличия "логического" события
- одна цельная точка подписки
- один экземпляр, создающий событие
- допустимость терминов "подписаться" и "отписаться" в конкретной ситуации

то используйте событие.

Если семантика события неприменима (например, это как-то тестовый статический callback) - используйте делегат.

Делегаты в "чистом" виде широко используются в стандартном фреймворке. Например, весь LINQ to Objects - манипуляции с коллекциями - построен на передаче делегатов типа `Func<T>`:

```
int[] someArray = ...;

int[] filtered = someArray.Where(i => i % 2 == 0).ToArray();
```

В этом примере `i => i % 2 == 0` - это объявлениение анонимной функции (через лямбда-выражение), и создание на основе ее делегата. Т.е. это аналог кода:

```
private static bool Filter(int i)
{
     return i ℅ 2 == 0;
}

Func<int, bool> filterDelegate = Filter;

int[] filtered = someArray.Where(filterDelegate).ToArray();
```

Comment: _"объявление анонимного делегата"_ -- говорят, что анонимных  делегатов не существует -- [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1748821/5673266). хотя в msdn есть [Пример анонимных делегатов](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms173235(v=vs.90).aspx), но видимо это одна из многих неточностей msdn.

Comment: @Stack это намеренное допущение, для облегчения понимания. В развернутом виде я дописал конкретную переменную-делегат, чтобы показать что все это на основе делегатов работает, а не за счёт магии. Считайте что я назвал "анонимной" именно её :)

Comment: @Stack перефорулировал, теперь все канонично.